# Setting the value of a complex custom input using GWT-Polymer

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, polymer

I'm building a GWT-Polymer application (I'm not an expert on Web technologies but I'm finding my way)

Now I need a complex input element for IP address in the same way the ssn-input demo here:

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/tree/master/demo

Entering the values in the browser and then reading the computed 'value' from the GWT side is ok but:

If I write to the 'value' property from the GWT side, how is that value decoded into those three _ssn properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/demo/ssn-input.html) you can already see that this is a custom element build for the porpuse of getting the ssn. so there is just no method declared to "just set the ssn". if you want to do that you have to set the values for ssn1, ssn1 and ssn3 on your own or add your own method to do so...

```
_setValue: function(ssn1, ssn2, ssn3) {
  this.ss1 = ssn1;
  this.ss2 = ssn2;
  this.ss3 = ssn3;
}
```

EDIT: are you using gwt-polymer-elements?

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me. Yes, I'm using gwt-polymer-elements. I tried to solved this by myself creating another property that, when set from GWT, does the same as your "_setValue" function (that property has an 'observer'). Then do 'this.ssn1 = ssn1.split(".")[0]', etc... so the _computeValue() from the example is also executed for each (finally, the 'value' property gets updated and the component is shown correctly in the browser...). I suppose it's better to have 3 properties and set their values as you suggest, isn't it?

Comment: well, ip adresses always have the same format so it shouldnt be a problem to split it.